# how to prepare data for cross validation in mnist dataset?

Tags: scikit-learn, keras, cross-validation, mnist

How to use k-fold cross validation for MNIST dataset?
I read article documentation on sci-kit learn ,in that example they used the whole iris dataset for cross validation.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
scores = cross_val_score(clf, iris.data, iris.target, cv=5)
scores
```

for example while importing mnist dataset in keras

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
(Xtrain,Ytrain),(Xtest,Ytest)=mnist_load()
```

in this dataset is already divided in test and train , so to apply cross validation on the entire dataset do we need to make Xtrain and Xtest as one entity to exploit the whole data.

Comment: Split your training set using sklearn `train_test_split` and making a validation set out of the training set itself or go for stratified sampling `X_train, X_val, Y_train, Y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size = 0.1, random_state=42)`

Comment: I don't want to split the data it will be taken by the crossvalidation function.

Comment: Yes it will be automatically done for you inside

Comment: So there is no need of train_test_split

Comment: Yep that's just another way to do the splits(not as efficient though, but its good for small data-sets) as `cross_validation` is costlier than normal splitting..... Cross-validation gives a more accurate measure of model quality, which is especially important if you are making a lot of modeling decisions. However, it can take more time to run, because it estimates models once for each fold. So it is doing more total work.

Comment: You should not use the test set for cross validation. Use a part of the training set only. This ensures that you are not overfitting to the test data.

Answer (score 1):

For the MNIST data,what you need to do is , apply cross validation on your training data for checking the performance of your model.
Then, If you are satisfied by the performance of the model, you can train it on the whole training set. 
After that, you will use the trained model to make predictions for the test dataset.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
scores = cross_val_score(clf, iris.data, iris.target, cv=5)
scores
```

They are not using the whole data for cross validation as such ( it's just an illusion)

When the `cv` argument is an integer, cross_val_score uses the `KFold` or `StratifiedKFold` strategies by default, the latter being used if the estimator derives from `ClassifierMixin`..

So it's kind of automated inside the call..

Check this kaggle kernel [link](https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/cross-validation)

Comment: Yes in here there is no pre division of data.but in mnist xtrain and xtest are separate

Comment: So we validate on a part of training set as we cant use the test set as such?

Comment: can't we concatenate the training and testing dataset and exploit the whole dataset and use k-fold cross validation

Comment: Do you have the labels for your test set?

Comment: yes its mnist dataset

Comment: You don't have labels for your test set, you have to predict them... If you do so, then what the point in training the model as either ways that will be cheating

Answer (score 0):

You can either validate your results on the test set or if you want to use KFold then you could first concatenate the train and test set first and then use KFold splitting to evaluate your results. Hope it helps!